# Formatting string - input string was not in correct format

Tags: c#, string.format

I would like to have a function to receive a string and format it to another string of the following format in C#: (testing is an input variable)

```
output:
@"{MyKey=testing}"
```

My simple program is below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = test("testing");
    }
    private static string test(string myKey)
    {
        string s = string.Format("@{\"MyKey={0}\"}", myKey);
        return s;
    }
}
```

There is no syntax error but I got this runtime error:

[image]

I know the string include special character but I wonder if it is possible to use string.Format to create the output I desire? How should I properly format the string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape those curly braces that should be a part of the string, by using double curly braces. See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1#how-do-i-include-literal-braces--and--in-the-result-string).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = test("testing");
        s.Dump();
    }
    private static string test(string myKey)
    {
        string s = string.Format("@{{\"MyKey={0}\"}}", myKey);
        return s;
    }
}
```

You can also use string interpolation like this:

```
string s = $"@{{\"MyKey={myKey}\"}}";
```

Comment: A note about *why* using double curleys solves the problem might be useful (i.e. that that's the escape sequence, maybe with a link to the docs)